# How can I format this kind of date time 2013-03-12T22:15:40+08:00 to "12 Mar 2012 02:15:40 UTC"?

Tags: javascript, datetime

I received my datetime from my database which return like this format

`2013-03-12T22:15:40+08:00`

what is this format? What is T and + represent to?

I would like to display my time into :

`12 Mar 2012 02:15:40 UTC`

I would like to display this time based on the timezone set in the browser. Thus, i should format this in Javascript, but not in backend. How can i acheive this in JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"T" for "time"; the "+" (or "-") represents the UTC offset. JavaScript actually parses this format fine in my browser:

```
> new Date('2013-03-12T22:15:40+08:00');
Date {Tue Mar 12 2013 14:15:40 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)}
```

Thus, if you want the format you've specified:

```
var formatDate = function(d) {
  var date = new Date(d);
  return date.getUTCDate() + ' ' +
         ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'][date.getUTCMonth()] + ' ' +
         date.getUTCFullYear() + ' ' +
         date.getUTCHours() + ':' +
         date.getUTCMinutes() + ':' +
         date.getUTCSeconds() + ' UTC';
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function toUTC(datestring) {
    var date = new Date(datestring);
    var months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
    return date.getUTCDate() + " " + 
           months[date.getUTCMonth()] + " " + 
           date.getUTCFullYear() + " " + 
           date.getUTCHours() + ":" + 
           date.getUTCMinutes() + ":" + 
           date.getUTCSeconds() + " UTC";
}
console.log(toUTC("2013-03-12T22:15:40+08:00"));
```

Gives `12 Mar 2013 14:15:40 UTC`. I suppose the UTC time should be 14hrs instead of 02hrs.

Answer (score 1):

The specifics are in the above answers - if this is all you're doing either seems like it would serve you well.  If you're going to do more date manipulation tho' then you may want to look at a date manipulation library.  JavaScript's handling of date's is weak at best so there are several to great ones to choose from but, for obvious reasons, I tend to like my own:

[DP_DateExtensions](http://depressedpress.com/javascript-extensions/dp_dateextensions/)

The Parse functions will get you a JS date from any predefined string and the Format functions will spit out whatever you need.